# C# - I cannot reference HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file, upload, httppostedfile

I am using MVC .NET in a distributed environment with CSLA and I **can** reference HttpPostedFileBase from one of my web layers (eg Website.MVC), but I **cannot** reference HttpPostedFileBase from a separate layer (lets call it OtherLayer.Web).

Any idea on what I need to do to be able to call HttpPostedFileBase ?
I am able to use HttpPostedFile in both layers - should I just use this instead?

The assembly references are basically the same - in Website.MVC I have:

```
namespace Website.Mvc.Controllers
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Web;
  using System.IO;
  using PetOrganizer.Mvc.Helpers;
  using TrupanionPetInsurance.Web;
```

Whereas in my other layer i have:

```
namespace OtherLayer.Web
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Collections.Specialized;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Net.Mail;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Web.Security;
  using System.Xml;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;
  using Csla;
  using iTextSharp.text;
  using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
  using TruDat.BusinessLayer;
  using TruDat.BusinessLayer.Billing;
  using TruDat.BusinessLayer.Data;
  using TruDat.BusinessLayer.Utility;
  using TrupanionPetInsurance.Web.EmailTemplateParser;
  using TruDat.BusinessLayer.DataServices;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make sure your project references the `System.Web.Abstractions` assembly which contains the [`HttpPostedFileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) type.

As confusing as it may seem, the [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) type lives in a separate assembly (`System.Web`) but the same exact namespace.

It is important to remember that the namespaces can span assemblies and the name of an assembly does not necessarily dictate the namespace of the types contained in it.  There is no `System.Web.Abstractions` *namespace* simply two assemblies that contain types in the `System.Web` namespace.

Once you have referenced both assemblies you can reference both types by their unqualified names with this single using statement:

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot reference System.Web.Abstractions - I get the error:

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Abstractions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi Teddy, my answer to your comment was too long so I updated my post above instead :)

Comment: Ok, co worker of mine figured this one out - I just had to add the reference to System.Web.Abstractions in OtherLayer.Web. I can reference HttpPostedFileBase now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! I knew that namespaces could span assemblies, but that is an easy lesson to forget. Definitely appreciate the insight!

Comment: As @Alundrathedreamwalker wrote but more updated- almost 7 years later and still a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your project references the System.Web.Abstractions assembly which contains the HttpPostedFileBase type.

Thanks, Andrew Hare, that did the trick, yet I believe that from .Net 4.0 and so on, System.Web.Abstractions is deprecated, and you should add reference to System.web instead.

In my case, that was the ultimate solution, after that

```
using System.Web;
```

worked, and therefore, HttpPostedFileBase was recognized.

Thanks.