# System.Web.Abstractions dll is Missing HttpPostedFileBase Class

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I'm following the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911151/c-sharp-i-cannot-reference-httppostedfilebase) so that I can reference the HttpPostedFileBase class in a C# project. But when I add the System.Web.Abstractions.dll reference to my project the compiler still doesn't recognize System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase.  When I go to the Class View > Project References > System.Web.Abstractions and click the triangle next to the dll I see no namespaces below it.  It's appears as if my System.Web.Abstractions.dll is void of any content.

The path for the dll is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Abstractions.dll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference to the `System.Web` assembly which is where the [HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) class is defined in .NET 4.0.

Comment: You know what, I've been looking at this for almost an hour and of course I found it right after I posted it.  But thanks, you're right.