# HttpPostedFileBase missing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm getting an error on `HttpPostedFileBase`:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpPostedFileBase'could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have already tried to use `using System.Web` but didn't work at all.

**Edit #1**

```
public IActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file.contentlength > 0)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.filename);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.mappath("~/app_data/uploads"), filename);
            file.saveas(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

I dont acctually have a reference folder [No references folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvU7O.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't mix and match tutorials and framework versions. You're on ASP.NET Core 2.0.8, which doesn't contain `HttpPostedFileBase`.

The [ASP.NET Core counterpart of `HttpPostedFileBase` is `IFormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: This is correct , but his tag mentions he is using `asp.net mvc.`

Comment: @storm: The tag was incorrectly applied. In the code, `IActionResult` is utilized, which only exists in Core. Therefore, the OP is using Core.

Comment: @CodeCaster how do I make it to save in a my db and not  a temp folder

Comment: @Dorin that's a new question altogether.

Comment: @CodeCaster , you are right, I have updated the answer to `asp.net core` and `asp.net mvc` , it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

**For ASP.NET CORE**

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1) post.

**For ASP.NET MVC**

**1.** Add reference for `System.Web` DLL in your project.

**2.** Using `using` directive add `using System.Web`  statement on top of your `.cs` file.

[image]

For more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911151/c-sharp-i-cannot-reference-httppostedfilebase) post.

Comment: on my reference tab I can only add reference to my project pages... https://imgur.com/a/y8WBGah

Comment: @DorinMunteanu , I have added screen shot please check, I mean , expand and check your references in your solution explorer for `System.Web` DLL , if you find it missing , just add it.

Comment: @DorinMunteanu , add that image in your question so others can help.

Comment: @DorinMunteanu , Don't just add the image link, edit and attach that screen shot  in your question so others can help.

Comment: Please mention tag as asp.net core , to get answers soon. @CodeCaster is correct one.

Comment: This is for ASP.NET Core. There is no `System.Web`, and it would be absolutely wrong to try to manually reference the DLL.

Comment: @ChrisPratt , you are correct, initially the OP had `asp.net mvc` tag added , so I though OP is after `asp.net mvc` solution. I have updated the answer to `asp.net core` and `asp.net mvc` , it may help others.